# Regex match string if not JUST whitespace (but allow whitespace if other chars present)

Tags: regex, match

I would like to match this:

```
*this string*
```

But not the following:

```
* *
```

I have tried this:

```
(?<!\*\*)(?<=\*)[^\*]+(?=\*)(?!\*\*)
```

But it will match the second use-case. To remedy this, I tried changing `[^\*]+` into `[^\*\s]+`, but then it won't match the first.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this: `^(\\+)(\\w+)(=)(\\s*\\S+\\s*)+$`

Comment: Well, try `(?<!\*\*)(?<=\*)[^\s*]+(?:\s*[^\s*]+)*(?=\*)(?!\*\*)`. Do you want to match `* this string*` or `*this string    *`? If yes, try `(?<!\*\*)(?<=\*)(?!\s+\*)[^*]+(?=\*)(?!\*\*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid matching *only whitespaces* in between two `*`s, you may add another lookahead, `(?!\s+\*)`:

```
(?<!\*\*)(?<=\*)(?!\s+\*)[^*]+(?=\*)(?!\*\*)
                ^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e2kxSn/1)

After making sure there are no `**` before the current location (with `(?<!\*\*)` and that there is one `*` in front (with `(?<=\*)`), the `(?!\s+\*)` negative lookahead will fail the match if there are 1+ whitespaces followed with `*` right after the current location.

Comment: Another possible solution - in case you just want `*` to be "glued" to word chars - is by adding word boundaries before and after `[^*]+` part: [`(?<!\*\*)(?<=\*)\b[^*]+\b(?=\*)(?!\*\*)`](https://regex101.com/r/e2kxSn/2).

Comment: This is perfect -- using the negative lookahead to (not) matching a whitespace, and then `*` was so simple :) Thanks.